# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError:

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jwt, postman

I am a student I am trying to create a booking api and I need to authenticate if the user that log in is an admin that is allowed to add courses and if not an admin would return access denied..

```
module.exports.addCourse = (reqBody) => {
    let newCourse = new Course({
        name : reqBody.name,
        description : reqBody.description,
        price : reqBody.price
    });
    
    return newCourse.save().then((course,error) => {

        if (!req.user.isAdmin) {

            return res.status(401).send({ message: "Access denied" });;

        } else if (reqBody.isAdmin = true){

            return true;

        };

    });

};


router.post("/",auth.verify,(req,res)=>{

    const data ={
        course: req.body,
        isAdmin: auth.decode(req.headers.authorization).isAdmin
    }
    courseController.addCourse(data).then(resultFromController=>res.send(resultFromController));
});

module.exports = router;
```

I wanted to add the course in my database if the user is an admin and does not allow if not an admin, I always get the error:

> (node:17308) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Course validation failed: name: Course is required, description: Description is required, price: Price is required

even though I have given the name description and price and also added the token in the postman.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using callback and promises? your syntax is not right...

// Alter 1

```
module.exports.addCourse = (reqBody) => {
  const newCourse = new Course({
    name : reqBody.name,
    description : reqBody.description,
    price : reqBody.price
  });

  return newCourse.save()
    .then((course) => {
     // ...code
    }).catch((err) => {
      // code error
    })
}

router.post("/",auth.verify,(req,res)=>{

  const data ={
      course: req.body,
      isAdmin: auth.decode(req.headers.authorization).isAdmin
  }
  courseController.addCourse(data).then(resultFromController=>res.send(resultFromController));
});

module.exports = router;
```

// alter 2

```
module.exports.addCourse = async (reqBody) => {
  const newCourse = new Course({
    name : reqBody.name,
    description : reqBody.description,
    price : reqBody.price
  });

  return await newCourse.save()
}

router.post("/",auth.verify, async (req,res)=>{

  const data ={
      course: req.body,
      isAdmin: auth.decode(req.headers.authorization).isAdmin
  }

  try {
    const response = await courseController.addCourse(data)
    // response
  } catch (err) {
    // error response
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

// alter 3

```
module.exports.addCourse = (reqBody) => {
  const newCourse = new Course({
    name : reqBody.name,
    description : reqBody.description,
    price : reqBody.price
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    newCourse.save()
      .then((course) => {
        resolve(course)
      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err)
      })
  })
}

router.post("/",auth.verify,(req,res)=>{

  const data ={
      course: req.body,
      isAdmin: auth.decode(req.headers.authorization).isAdmin
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    courseController.addCourse(data)
      .then((resultFromController) => {
        resolve(res.send(resultFromController))
      }).catch((error) => { 
        reject(res.send('error'))
      })

  })
});
```